# MySQL Permission: Still getting ACCESS DENIED even after granting ALL PRIVILEGES

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

So I granted all privileges to root in MySQL

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on *.* to 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' with GRANT OPTION;
```

So after running this i get:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But after running my code on Pycharm which accesses a local DB, I'm getting this:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

I'm pretty new to Python and MySQL, so I'm gonna need pretty simple yet detailed advice if anyone is willing to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

download the MySQL python connector from here
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

then run this within a file:

```
import mysql.connector
con = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", password="xxxx", host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
cur = con.cursor()
```

After running your query make sure to commit any changes and close connections:

```
con.commit()
cur.close()
con.close()
```